# dbus_g_proxy_call to freedesktop "Get" method gives error Expected type gchararray, got type code 'v'

Tags: c, glibc, dbus

I understand that the error message is indicating that it got a type `variant`.  What I don't understand is why.  This call seems to follow the same format as the [Freedesktop DBus Tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html).  I assigned `proxy = NULL` before the `dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name` call and I checked that `proxy != NULL` after so I'm fairly confident that `proxy` isn't the problem.  How can I correct this?

```
if (!dbus_g_proxy_call(proxy, "Get", &err, G_TYPE_STRING, 
"org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player", G_TYPE_STRING, 
"PlaybackStatus", G_TYPE_INVALID, 
G_TYPE_STRING, &pb_status, G_TYPE_INVALID))
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR : %s\n", err->message);
```

Output:

```
 ERROR : Expected type gchararray, got type code 'v'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Get method returns a variant type, not a string type.

Side note- http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/

> GDBus (D-Bus support in GLib)
>
> Since version 2.26, GLib includes a D-Bus binding. This is intended to
>   replace the DBus-GLib bindings and many applications have started
>   migrating their code. See the documentation for the high-level and
>   low-level API for more details.
>
> DBus-GLib (obsolete)
>
> New GLib applications should use the D-Bus support built into GLib.
>   See above.